# Ssh on unix, ssh_config file not working

Tags: bash, ssh, configuration, macos

I use `ssh` on my mac and I was deleting know hosts in the `/ssh` folder. Unfortunately the ssl package stopped working because of my ssh_config. I am a little unsure how to fix this, I have tried using  level 3 verbosing `-vvv` to give me more detail, it keeps coming back to `$SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling`.
Is this a socket that ssh is using ?
Preferably  I would like to uninstall ssh and reinstall but I do not know the mac M1s default package manager that handles `ssh`
If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be really appreciated :)

```
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 2.8.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.65 [192.168.1.65] port 22.
```

Comment: Is that all the debug you get, or did you stop pasting there because you thought that was the reason for the problem? If there's more, please add all of it to your question

Comment: @roaima :  Ican confirm that this is the only thing that's shown. I was (am) searching for clues as I just got the logs from one of our users. I asked for the full debug (-vvv) and she just got a two more lines that look pretty irrelevant: `debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/XXXXX/.ssh/known_hosts'